# Live Speech to Text Transcription in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, speech-recognition, ibm-watson

This is my first post ever, so I hope it is alright.
I am working on a Raspberry Pi Zero W, and I am trying to make a live speech-to-text translator. I have researched, and I think I need to use the SpeechRecognition module, and I have been doing that and did end up writing a program that does what I need it to using the Google speech to text module, and it does the job just not live.
I think for me to make it transcribe it live, I need to use the IBM Watson Speech to Text with something called Websockets.

I can not seem to find a lot of information about those two together yet alone any code, if any of you have any experience with transcribing live to text using this or any other way in Python I would really appreciate if you could point me in the right direction, and any code would be fantastic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google have live speech to text transcription API. They also provide the source code to get you started on it. Check this [github page](https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech/blob/master/samples/microphone/transcribe_streaming_mic.py). All it does is it listens to your microphone and sends you the text version of whatever you are saying in real time.

This is an example software that works right out of the box. All you need to do is to run with your `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` saved in your [environment variables](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries).

If you have already used it once, you should have set up a billing account already. If not, please do so [here](https://console.cloud.google.com/billing).