# Read rtmp live streaming video using python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, rtmp, live-streaming, audio-analysis

I am streaming a session using rtmp server(NGINX). I got the stream url as
`rtmp://ip:port/live/stream_name`.
How can I read the live stream in my python code(or any other) to do live transcription?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Live Speech to Text Transcription in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65987662/live-speech-to-text-transcription-in-python)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But, I would like to do transcription from the rtmp stream directly

Answer (score 2):

You have to use one of libraries that allow such process, one of the most commonly used is OpenCV.

*Install through pip:*

```
python3 -m pip install opencv-python
```

*Code sample*

```
import cv2  # Import OpenCV lib

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('<your RTMP url>') # Open video source as object
while cap.isOpened():  # Untill end of file/error occured
    ret, frame = cap.read()  # Read frame as object - numpy.ndarray, ret is a confirmation of a successfull retrieval of the frame
    if ret: 
        <your code here>
    else:
        break
cap.release()
```